# LINQ from string array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string like this, which is dynamic and can be any length from 1 to 1000 parts in the format of id^part~:

```
string Parts = "1^PartOne~2^PartTwo~3^Part3~4^PartFour"
```

Is it possible to convert this into an iList of strings like the following using LINQ?

```
PartOne
PartTwo
PartThree
PartFour
```

or do I just need to split twice and add to a list manually?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using regular `string.Split` and `Select`?

```
var list = Parts.Split('~').Select(x => x.Split('^')[1]);
```

You can do a `.ToList()` to make it a `IList` in the end, as requested.

It splits the various elements (`1^PartOne`), and then splits them again to take the last part (`PartOne`)

Comment: Thanks. Started to doubt myself.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd prefer a `Dictionary<string, string>` over a `List<string>` since you can represent both key and value:

```
string parts = "1^PartOne~2^PartTwo~3^Part3~4^PartFour";

var dict = parts.Split(new[] { '~' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(part => part.Split('^'))
                .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method:

```
int n = 0;
var result = Parts
    .Split(new char[] {'^','~'}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(x => !int.TryParse(x,out n));
```

Since this is a regular sequence of the form "number^text~", we use `Split` to split on the special characters and filter out the purely numeric parts to get the text required.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CWUO57556)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code. It is working as your requirement. Must try it.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Singh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Parts = "1^PartOne~2^PartTwo~3^PartThree~4^PartFour";
            string[] data = new string[5];
            data = Parts.Split('^', '~');


            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
            {
                i++;
                string names = data[i];
                Console.WriteLine(names.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]